# Prestashop: Display Categories tree in module back office

Tags: php, treeview, e-commerce, prestashop, categories

I am making a payment gateway and It could happen that depending on the shop manager, taxes maybe already included in the price, or not. So, when included, the tax field would be 0 and I need to get the price value without the tax. I came up with the idea of making a categories tree in the module back office where the shop manager may specify each category tax, so if it's included in the price, I can calculate it looking what category the product belongs to.

My problem, I do not know how to display the categories tree in the back office. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `renderCategoryTree` method of the `Helper` class (`classes/helper/Helper.php`):

```
$helper = new Helper();
$categoryTree = $helper->renderCategoryTree();
```

Take a look at `modules/blocklayered/blocklayered.php` for an example.

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /vagrant/classes/helper/HelperTreeCategories.php on line 185

Answer (score 1):

I am using HelperTreeCategories helper.

```
        $categories = new HelperTreeCategories('associated-categories-tree', 'Выберите категории');
    $categories->setUseCheckBox(1)
                ->setUseSearch(1);
            $categories->render(); // To show categires select with checkboxes as on product category association page
```